# SpringBoot 3 + ReactJS + Auth0

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, auth0

I'm just starting a new project from scratch and decided for Kotlin with SpringBoot 3 with ReactJS on frontend and Auth0 as Identity Provider. As far as I like SpringBoot I get seriously confused with what is the recommended way of doing auth in such a setup.
Let me elaborate on couple of crucial things:

1. I want to utilise Auth0 functionalities for registering users / social login etc. BUT I need to store more information about the user
2. I want to create more sophisticated relations so that users have organisations they can invite other people to.
3. WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter seems to be deprecated and there are not many sources that clearly explain how to configure that FilterChain in SpringBoot 3. What is more, many of them focus then on Spring being an Identity Provider which further complicates things.
4. After JWT is validated with Auth0, I need information about the user also from my database (I store some additional informations about the user after all)

Can someone explain to me the steps of creating Security Configuration in new SpringBoot having in mind the prerequisites I stated?

Comment: Trying to summarize and understand what is your issue. You want to build a REST API with a security layer using kotlin+spring+auth0. I think how the frontend is built doesn't matter. Also you want to save some extra info about the user. Auth0 let you save [custom metadata](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-accounts/metadata/metadata-fields-data) for users and also for the app. Not sure if that is enough or you need to save some info on your side to later be processed. Please edit your post trying to be more specific. If you have more than one question, ask each one in different posts

Comment: Frontend does matter, as my main focus right now is selecting a proper AUTH configuration, and how you do integration with Auth0 (Implicit Flow/ Auth Code Flow/ PKCE) impacts how you configure whole setup. And I want to know which one to use and possibly the best practices to configure it

Answer (score 1):

I created an example last year that shows how to use [React and Spring Boot together with Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot/).

It uses Auth code flow on the server and uses good ol' session cookies to secure communications with the client. This is the most secure way to implement OAuth between the two frameworks because an access token never lives in the browser.

Comment: not a fan of session cookies. It requires to keep track of those and beats the whole purpose of stateless auth

Comment: I've never had to keep track of session cookies in a Java app. If you need to distribute the session, Spring Session + Redis works nicely.

Comment: But if you use Spring Session + Redis then you're storing sessions, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, but there's nothing you need to do (as a developer) to keep track of them. Spring handles it all for you.

Comment: Still stateful though.

Answer (score 1):

I also have written a tutorial for [SPAs and Spring on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).

I use `spring-cloud-gateway` as BFF between the SPA (secured with sessions) and the Spring resource server (REST API secured with OAuth2 access tokens).

The BFF in my tutorial is configured to accept identities from 3 different sources, one of the 3 being Auth0.

For security reasons, the JWT never reaches the SPA. User info is served by the backend (the BFF in my tutorial, but could be any resource server behind it). You can retrieve whatever business data and attach it to the response in this service, before returning the user info payload...

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of such configuration, but what potential issues did you recognise when it comes to JWT reaching SPA?

Comment: SPA can't keep a secret: as most software executed on remote devices, code can be reverse engineered to read secrets (in SPAs, this is trivial) => OAuth2 clients running on remote devices (SPAs and mobile apps) are "public" clients => it is pretty easy for a malicious client to be delivered tokens. BFF running on your server can (and should) be an OAuth2 confidential client (with a secret)

Comment: Also the SPAs configured as OAuth2 client need to  access the OAuth2 tokens. This means that this tokens are exposed to Javascript code, which considerably increases the attack surface (not to talk about tokens storage on clients which frequently very insecure). As a contrast, session cookies should be flagged as HTTP only and, as so, not accessible to Javascript code.

Comment: Ok, now I know what you're referring to. Yes, 100% agree. One thing I would mention is that if you use PKCE, negotiating tokens should not be such an issue, storing them... that's whole another story (XSS). I was a bit confused though, what you meant by session cookies. I think using auth code flow is generally safest (but puts more pressure on backend), in my case, I can merge BFF with my API to one monolith for now though. I wouldn't like to store tokens though. I prefer to call Auth0 and be stateless, as long as possible ;)

Comment: The resource server(s) behind the BFF are stateless. Only the BFF itself can't be. Authorization code is used (with PKCE) to provide the BFF (not the browser) with OAuth2 tokens (access, and optionally ID and refresh). You should consider that this pattern is now used by almost all editors: Google, Facebook, Github LinkedIn, Stackoverflow, etc., all use OAuth2 but none exposes tokens to browsers nor uses public clients.

Comment: That is all fine. Although I'm not sure why you need PKCE in the all-backend flow. Authorisation Code Flow should be enough, right? Now, what is the reason to hide access_token behind session_cookie? Access_token can still be returned, simply ass http-only cookie with SameSite=strict to prevent CSRF, am I missing anything?

Comment: You're right PKCE is not needed when authorization code is returned to, and tokens fetched from, the server (which is the case with BFF). For tokens to be exchanged as HTTP only cookies, it would have to be set by the server.

Comment: Yes that's exactly my point. Someone suggested to use Spring Session + Redis which is what session cookies are about. Then access_token is not used in cookie but instead persisted somewhere with BFF and exchanged with session_cookie which could be an opaque string which btw. makes sense in some scenarios (for example mobile with poor network), but it's not stateless anymore

Comment: Authorization is a state. OAuth2 clients always are stateful: it has to store tokens somewhere, it is just better when this state is stored in session on your server rather than on remote devices by some random framework => write business logic in stateless resource servers and use a stateful middleware to store tokens (`spring-cloud-gateway` does that pretty well and requires little effort to configure and maintain)

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be stateful by design. That was the whole point of inventing JWTs. The signatures of tokens (both access and refresh) are enough to validate. Now, there are other requirements pushed on IdPs such as invalidations of all tokens (log out from all devices), and yes, I guess you store them, however you don't have to, you can store "logout time". But I think we do tradeoffs with IdPs to be able to invalidate specific sessions, so IdPs have to keep track of them. And if you claim your BFF is not part of the API but rather "supportive" domain - sure

Comment: Yes, **clients are stateful by design** (as well as authorization servers). JWT is a state and clients need to store this state between requests. Only resource servers can be stateless because the state is passed with each request (inside a JWT or through introspection). And yes, I claim that the BFF is not part of API: it is a separate process, listening on another socket and the API can be consumed directly by any other OAuth2 client (BFF is just a proxy for user agents which are not OAuth2 clients).